# Error on running SFDX CLI command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

When I try to run a command -- (for example: sfdx update), I get the following message on the cmd prompt:

Attempting to contact update site..
S3 host is not reachable..

Has anyone here come across this message earlier. Any inputs would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am facing same issue. Were you able to solve this issue? If yes, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a proxy issue. Had same problem here on internal network (with a nasty proxy), switched to guest network and didn't have it anymore and it got updated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was that Visual Studio Code was running updates at the same time. After VS completed and restarted a few times, I was able to run >sfdx update